# How to achieve thread concurency in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am working with a Java Swing application, where I have a main frame and multiple panels which I commute between by setting them visible or not and in the same time, I am instantiating a class which is running a while loop in the background. Now, the problem is: the panels don't appear unless that while loop ends, but I would like to let the user click some buttons while the while loops continues in the background, without even him knowing about that. Here is a small example of my code:

```
        startPage.setVisible(false);
        lblError.setVisible(false);     
        new QuestionPage(Integer.parseInt(fieldUserID.getText()));
```

`QuestionPage` has a while loop going, and I would like to not freeze the whole application until that is finished, but to let that while loop run in the background. So far I tried doing 2 threads by extending the Thread class, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

[EDIT]

Here is my `NEXT` button after using a SwingWorker in order to send in background the while loop which happens in `QuestionPage` class and to carry on with swing operations on the main frame

```
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
            if (validateInput(fieldUserID.getText(), fieldAge.getText(), fieldSex.getSelectedItem().toString(), fieldExperience.getText())) {   
                startPage.setVisible(false);
                lblError.setVisible(false); 
                SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void doInBackground() {
                        new QuestionPage(Integer.parseInt(fieldUserID.getText()));
                        return null;
                        }                           
                    };                             
            } else {
                lblError.setVisible(true);
            }               
        };                  
    });
```

Comment: Swing is not thread, you should not be updating the UI from out side the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. Based on your description, you're blocking the EDT

Comment: Instead of using a loop, try using a Timer or Swing Timer to schedule actions to happen.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. I'd also encourage you to add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because right now, it's all just guess work

Comment: So in order to understand your answer @madprogrammer, I followed this tutorial and I learnt about SwingWorkers https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html. Is this what your response is pointing at?

Comment: The answer to your question would depend on what you are attempting to achieve, because the question lacks sufficient context, it's impossible to provide you with a concrete answer.  A `SwingWorker` or Swing `Timer` might solve your problem

Comment: Please see my edit above. What I'm trying to achieve is simply described in the question itself. I have a class which when instantiated creates a new JPanel and runs a while loop inside that, but in the same time I want to dispose the current frame. Basically, all I need is a background process while the Swing application doesn't freeze so the user can still interact with the buttons. Am I using the `SwingWorker` in the right way?

Comment: I don't want to wait for that panel instantiation to finish, along with the while loop, but rather send it in background while the Swing app carry's on with its rendering and panels changes. I get the app to not freeze now, but the `QuestionPage` doesn't get instantiated anymore

Answer (score 0):

[ANSWER]

The trick is to use a SwingWorker to send the long running task in the background and to also call `execute()` on it. Here is a minimal working example for a `Start` button event listener:

```
 // Send long running task in background
                SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void doInBackground() {
                        new QuestionPage(Integer.parseInt(fieldUserID.getText()));
                        return null;
                        }                           
                    };
                    worker.execute();
```